# Show details dynamically

Tags: global-payments-api

"I have created a card design positioned to the right of hosted fields, and I'm looking for a way to dynamically display the cardholder's name, card number, and card expiry details on that card when a user enters their information into the hosted fields. How can I implement this functionality?"

i am expecting how can achieve this.